# Symfony/Doctrine: Transaction involving multiple objects/functions

Tags: mysql, transactions, symfony1, doctrine, rollback

I want to perform a certain set of operations on multiple models/tables using Doctrine with Symfony. Here is what I'm doing:

```
public function myFunc()
{
        $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
        try {
            $conn->beginTransaction();
            $prop_trans->save($conn);
            self::doSomething1($conn);
            $bill_appor->save($conn);
            // Final Committ
            $conn->commit();
            return $prop_trans;
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            if ($conn)
                $conn->rollback();
            throw $exc;
        }
}

public function doSomething($conn)
{
       $obj = new Trans();
       // this function might create & save another child record
       $obj->doSomething2($conn); 
       $obj->save($conn);

}
```

However, when there is an exception (code or db level), I wonder if the rollback works, as I see some records being saved.

My understanding is that, as long as I've opened a connection, begun a transaction, all methods using the connection $conn are running in the same transaction. If something fails, all rollback.

I also tried to use savepoints, but I haven't been able to work with them. Can someone pl tell me if passing the connection around is enough to make everything run the transaction?
Is it because a MySQL auto_committ attribute is set or something?
Thanks

Comment: code is more or less pseudo-code, so pl ignore errors, such as a object method being statically called

Answer (score 2):

Well, transactions are supported only over InnoDB tables and I believe, that some of your tables are MyISAM. So, rollback works only on InnoDB ones and you see changes to MyISAM ones left intact.

Comment: Thanks mate. I checked that all tables are InnoDB, but somehow the database is MyISAM. How do I change the DB type? databases.yml? since it is created by the doctrine:build-db task. Thanks again

Comment: @Prasad How do you know your database is innodb? There is no such definition. Database doesn't have any ENGINE by itself.

Comment: Thanks FractalizeR. I checked the DB summary in PHPMyAdmin (for MySQL). The "Type" of each table is InnoDB. The summary row shows "15 tables" and the next column says "MyIsam". But then again, is there another reason why rollbacks dont work as expected? aren't they tied to a transaction/connection?

Comment: @Prasad: I think that the "MyIsam" that you see is the default option and not the actual engine

Answer (score 1):

just try

```
catch (Exception $exc) {

                $conn->rollback();

        }
```

in your try ctach

or 
just put try catch on your other function as well